# Портирование куска кода (класс BigIntiger) с Java в C#

Tags: java, c#

Доброго времени суток.

Как портировать данный код на C#?

```
BigInteger mod = new BigInteger(1,new byte[]{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1});
System.out.println(mod);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Классы `BigInteger` в C# и Java используют различное внутреннее представление.

Простой и надёжный пособ: преобразуйте число Java в строку (в вашем случае "166599134359138271745"), а потом распарсите его в C# с помощью `BigInteger.Parse`.

Если вам критична производительность, то можете пошаманствовать с изменением порядка байтов (little endian, big endian) и добавлением нулевого байта в начале массива. См. [Java BigInteger vs Mono .net BigInteger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119076).

А вообще, вот так ваше число получилось:

```
Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }));
```